# How to submit data to a webpage using xpaths and the such

Tags: python, html, xml

I'm in the process of writing an API for a craigslist like website, and I finished the data getting part using html from lxml.
Now I want to submit data (login info, things to be posted ...) to the website.
Can I do it using lxml or do I have to use another module ?

Comment: to send data you have to use `requests` or `urllib.request` or similar (or `Selenium`). `lxml` is used only to search information in file `HTML` or `XML` which you could get from server using  `requests` or `urllib.request` or similar (or `Selenium`)

Comment: There's a number field, a password field and a login button how do I "invoke" the button

Comment: when you click button then browser sends to server `POST` request with all data and you can see this request in `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox. Using module `requests` or `urllib.request` you can also send `POST` request - ie. `reuqests.post(url, data, ...)` - and you don't have to click any button. But if you use Selenium to control web browser then it has functions to open page, fill field and click button.

Answer (score 0):

As @furas mentioned you can use <kbd>requests</kbd> module for posting the data (login in your case).

Here is the simple example where you can use requests module for both <kbd>get</kbd> and <kbd>post</kbd>

```
import requests
# get the token
resp = requests.get("https://www.botoxcosmetic.com/sc/api/findclinic/GetFadToken?_=1556315102966")
# print the token
print (resp.json())
# storing all the input data in dataI. In your case you have to replace them with username and password (check the API documentation or devtools to make sure the param name(s) is correct)
dataI = {'ZipCode':'10022','MileRadius':'1','PerPage':'5','Token':resp.json()}
# post the data (you don't have to click on any submit button) and capture the response to the the post.
resp = requests.post("https://www.botoxcosmetic.com/sc/api/findclinic/FindSpecialists",data= dataI)
# print the response from post call
print(resp.json())
```